# Google Sheets - Autosort Script issues

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas

I am trying to sort data descending based upon column B (2) which has different numbers in each cell. EG: B8 = 99, B14 = 70, etc. I'm intending for it to autosort and do it onEdit. I'm not good at coding, like at all. So I watched a YouTube vid and came up with this, but it still doesn't work.

```
function autoSort(e){
    const row = e.range.getRow()
    const column = e.range.getColumn()
    const ss = e.source
    const currentSheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
    const currentSheetName = currentSheet.getSheetName()

    if(!(currentSheetName === "Roster" && column === 9 && row >= 8)) return

    const range = currentSheet.getRange(8,5,21,22)

    range.sort({column: 2, ascending: false})

}


function onEdit(e){

  autoSort (e)
```

Comment: I haven't checked the other things but at a quick glance the closing curly bracket of onEdit seems to be missing

Comment: In addition to what Daniele said, what error are you getting when you run this? From reading through it, it should work just fine though.

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. There's either a typo in your question, or a logic error in your code. `currentSheet.getRange(8,5,21,22)` defines the range "E8:Z28" and `range.sort({column: 2, ascending: false})` will sort that range based on the second column (Column F). Column B (which is the column that you describe in your question) NEVER comes into it. You say _but it still doesn't work_. Would you please describe EXACTLY what you expect to happen, and EXACTLY what happens instead. If there was an error message (which I doubt), please show the full message.